# What type of encryption used in rails 5.2 ENCRYPTED CREDENTIALS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Rails 5.2 replaces both secrets with encrypted credentials. We cannot use plain text credentials. So i'm trying to understand the encryption type used in rails 5.2 ENCRYPTED CREDENTIALS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encrypted credentials or more generically, [`EncryptedConfiguration`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-0/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb) and [`EncryptedFile`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-0/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb) in Rails use the generic [`ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor` class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-0/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb) under the hood.

Here, it is used with an [AES-128-GCM](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb#L22) cipher to encrypt and authenticate the data. This is a form of [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) which ensures that the encrypted data can not be views in plaintext and can not be changed undetected as long as the encryption key remains secret.

This `MessageEncryptor` class is used in various places in Rails already for quite some time, including to provide the encrypted session cookies.

Comment: Stefan Wintermeyer shared this link  https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-use-aes-128-bit-key for detailed information.